# Error when trying to save a Flow | Something went wrong: Hmm, that didn't work. Please try again

Tags: visual-workflow

When trying to save a new version of a Flow, or even as a New Flow I get the following attached error. Have you seen this before? How is it solved?

I didnt received a notification email with more info, and I am not sure how to setup a debug for this kind of error.
I have closed the session and same issue.
It doesnt seem to be related with the changes that I made, because I just tried changing something else and I get the same error.
I also tried saving it as a New Flow but no luck.

[image]

Comment: ah, these are tricky - there's a config error somewhere in the Flow that is not displaying on Save. Hopefully you have a previous version. I'd start with the previous version and selectively add back in each new element, saving as you go